# How to get https/backend_request_count metric of load balancer in GCP with python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I want to get **https/backend_request_count** metric.

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp?hl=ja#loadbalancing/https/backend_request_count

Is that possible to get it by python?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. I followed this [reading metric document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/reading-metrics#timeseries-list-data) and filtered it with backend_request_count.

What I did to get the filter is followed [Google Cloud Metrics backend_request_count](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-loadbalancing), and built the filter.

> The "metric type" strings in this table must be prefixed with
> loadbalancing.googleapis.com/. That prefix has been omitted from the
> entries in the table.

Following the instructions above, the filter will be like this:

```
metric.type = "loadbalancing.googleapis.com/https/backend_request_count"
```

Applying this filter in the code, the code will look like this:

```
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
import time

client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
## Don't forget to replace this dummy project_id with your actual project_id ##
project_name = f"projects/your-project-id-here" 
interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval()

now = time.time()
seconds = int(now)
nanos = int((now - seconds) * 10 ** 9)
interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval(
    {
        "end_time": {"seconds": seconds, "nanos": nanos},
        "start_time": {"seconds": (seconds - 1200), "nanos": nanos},
    }
)

results = client.list_time_series(
    request={
        "name": project_name,
        "filter": 'metric.type = "loadbalancing.googleapis.com/https/backend_request_count"', 
        "interval": interval,
        "view": monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL,
    }
)
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

This will yield a [ListTimeSeriesResponse](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/ListTimeSeriesResponse), here is the snippet response of the above code.

[image]